# How can I fix: File `jacsat.cfg' not found error in a ACS Publications?

Tags: errors, templates, article, overleaf

I have to publish an article using ACS template.

I have open the template that I have found in [this website](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/acs-publications) using Overleaf but I have got this error:

```
File `jacsat.cfg' not found error
```

Is there a way I can fix this error directly in Overleaf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File `jacsat.cfg` is (or rather was) a part of `achemso` and so really should be available if the class is. However, there was a rename relatively recently, so newer releases use `achemso-jacsat.cfg`. This all happens 'together' so is transparent to users. However, if you've got some 'local' files you might run into a problem. Looking at the template you've linked to, they've put a copy of `achemso.cls` into the same directory as the `.tex` file, so it's a 'fixed' one, but they've omitted the `.cfg` files. This is what causes the problem: the versions are mismatched.

In the list of files on Overleaf you should delete `achemso.cls` and `achemso.bst`, leaving just the files `achemso-demo.tex` and `achemso-demo.bib`. The LaTeX system will then find the class file and configuration files from the 'system-wide' installation, which do match and allow compilation.

Comment: I'll report the issues here to the site maintainer!